# X equivalent of 'screen' utility

Tags: linux, xorg, gnu-screen

Under unix/linux, there is this extremely useful program `screen`: it's for bash, text-only, and I can detach a session, log out (the session is still running though), log in later (even from a different computer) and resume the session exactly as I left it.

My question is, is there an equivalent to `screen` for X?

So what I want to do is: work remotely with `ssh -X` in an X-session on a remote linux machine, log out, then later log in from a different computer again with `ssh -X` and then re-attach the X-session; practically resuming work from the moment when I logged out before. Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am having success in using [xpra](http://xpra.org/)

Comment: Yup, the author describes `xpra` as "`screen` for X". Useful indeed.

Comment: my god this is good. The long waited bastard offspring of VNC and X11. I'm SOOOO hooked.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use VNC?

So long as you don't log out (thus closing all your running applications etc) your system will stay in the exact same state no matter how many times you disconnect/reconnect.

Comment: With X-forwarding, the applications can appear as running on the computer you're forwarding them to, whereas with VNC you're limited to working inside a forwarded desktop. That is, X-forwarding gives a more native feel.

Answer (score 2):

More a question for unix.stack but have a look at [x11vnc](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/). Things will work a bit differently, you won't be using ssh -X but use the VNC protocol. In shared mode, disconnecting VNC will not log out the X session.

Answer (score 0):

I use [NoMachine](http://www.nomachine.com/) at work and at home. It uses ssh. I happen to use the Windows client, but clients are available for Linux and Mac, too.